# Add Save Option to QR Code Scanner using Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: java, android, qr-code

Please help me out... I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 and I have a code that scan the QR code and now I want to save the scanned data. My code just scan the code and display it in a text format with options share via SMS,Email and history and No save option. I need to save this text document. How can I add save option?

Below is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static TextView tvresult;
    private  Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvresult);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScanActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

**ScanActivity.java**

```
public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{

    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
        setContentView(mScannerView);                // Set the scanner view as the content view
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
        mScannerView.startCamera();          // Start camera on resume
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        // Do something with the result here
        // Log.v("tag", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
        // Log.v("tag", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)

        MainActivity.tvresult.setText(rawResult.getText());
        onBackPressed();

        // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
        //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }
}
```

How could I achieve that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the result of the `rawResult.getText()` method to preferences or SQLite Database

Comment: Thank You Sir. Since im a fresher I dnt knw how to write that function @VolkanSahin45

Comment: this link will help you https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: Sir I am beginner to android studio. So I need help, how to write the save button option to the qr-code scanner using Zxing functions.Please help me Sir.....

Comment: Look some tutorials for shared preferences